# Test for equation irrational

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, numbers

I'm making a number data shower, which show the data of a number, like even or odd.
Now I stopped at irrational numbers, how can I test for is it that?

Something like this:

```
alert(isIrrational(Math.sqrt(9)));
```

Comment: All (IEEE) floating point numbers are rational. sqrt(2.0) returns an approximation to the irrational number whose square is 2.0

Comment: @dmuir So you'd want to determine if the approximation has a reasonable denominator (like 1/3 v. 54,608,393 / 38,613,965 ~ √2).

Comment: This is actually a really interesting question, if you phrase it as, given x which is a rational number, is sqrt(x) rational or irrational? Of course, there's no point to calculating a numerical approximation such as Math.sqrt(x) since floats are all rational; you have to look at the properties of x and answer the question without resorting to a calculation. I speculate that when x is an integer, that if sqrt(x) is not also an integer (which can be determined in more than one way) then sqrt(x) is irrational. But I could be mistaken, you'll want to look at the details.

Comment: @Robert Dodier: Yes, unique prime factorization extends to rational numbers. If a/b is rational and not an integer, then (a/b)^2 is rational and not an integer because there are some negative even exponents of primes in the prime factorization. So, the only integers that are squares of rationals are squares of integers.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context, but you might want to say that floating point numbers that are very close to simple rational numbers should be identified as rational, and otherwise they should be identified as possible irrational numbers. You have to choose definitions for "very close" and "simple rational numbers."

For relatively small numbers (say absolute value under 100), you might say that the simple rational numbers are those with small denominators, such as 2/3, say those with denominators under 100. Your definition of "very close" might be that the absolute magnitude of the difference is small, say under 10^-6, or you might require numbers to be closer than 1000 times the square the of denominator. For most purposes, this is enough.

The theory of rational approximations to a number with small denominators is part of number theory called Diophantine approximation. One tool you might use is the [simple continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) expansion of a number, such as 
`pi = 3+1/(7+1/(15+1/(1+1/292+...)))` and `e-1=1+1/(1+1/(2+1/(1+1/(1+1/(4+1/(1+1/(1+1/(6+...))).` You can compute these recursively although you run out of precision quickly. When you truncate such an expression, you get a good rational approximation, such as pi~3, or pi~22/7, pi~355/113, or e~193/71. These give the candidate rational numbers with small denominators which are close. Large coefficients in the simple continued fraction mean the number has a good rational approximation.

Some rational numbers will not be detected to be rational this way, such as 1/500 if you use a threshold of 100 for the denominator. However, you would be able to identify 1/3.0f as rational, and Math.sqrt(2.0)*Math.sqrt(8.0), which you would reject Math.sqrt(2.0).

I don't know if there is a standard way to determine the complexity of a large float like 6.73241 x 10^31. That could even be an integer, but you don't have the precision to tell. You might say that numbers close to smooth integers are simple. Smooth means that there are no large primes in the prime factorization. While factoring large numbers in general is hard, factoring smooth numbers is not so bad because you only have to test a few possible prime factors. When you can't even test nearby numbers for smoothness, you might compare the logarithm of the number with combinations of the logarithms of small primes. This might mean that a large prime would not be identified as a rational number, but in case you care, record-setting prime numbers are typically 1 away from smooth numbers, e.g., 2**57885161-1.

Between extremely large floating point numbers and decimals, you might use some sort of complexity measure which uses a combination of the simplicity of the possible numerators and the simplicity of the possible denominators. So, for numbers between 10^6 and 10^9, you might decide that you only tolerate denominators up to 10, and you might require that the difference be smaller than 10^-4 from one of these numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Determining whether `sqrt(rational)` is irrational or not is fairly simple. Here is how:

Write the `rational` argument as `m/n` with `m` and `n` integers and coprime, i.e., `gcd(n, m) = 1`. Now assume that there exists a rational square root `r` of `m/n`. If `r = s/t` with `s` and `t` integers and coprime, we would have:

```
s^2/t^2 = rˆ2 = m/n
```

or

```
n * s * s = m * t * t
```

In particular `s * s` would divide `m * t * t` and since `s` and `t` have no common primes, `s * s` would actually divide `m`. In other words, we would have (1) `s * s <= m` and (2) `m % (s * s) = 0` (mod operation). So, all candidates for `s` could be computed very easily with the following routine

1. **[Initialize]** Let `S` be an empty collection of divisors and `d := 1`.
2. **[Check]** If `m % (d * d)` = 0, then add `d` to `S`
3. **[Increment]** Set `d := d + 1`
4. **[Repeat]** If `d * d <= m` go to 2
5. **[End]** Return `S`

In the same way we may conclude that `t` satisfies (1) `t * t <= n` and (2) `n % (t * t) = 0`. And we could use the same routine as above to compute the collection `T` of all squared divisors of `n` (just replace `S` with `T` and `m` with `n`.)

Finally, we would have to enumerate all pairs `(s, t)` in `S x T` looking for a pair such that

```
m * s * s = n * t * t
```

using exact integer arithmetic, which is perfectly possible. If no pair `(s, t)` is found, then `sqrt(m/n)` would be irrational.

**Example**

Let's pretend we don't know that `sqrt(100/81)` is the rational `10/9` and let's deduce it using the algorithm given above:

First we compute the collection `D` of squared divisors of `100`. Here is a trace of the algorithm:

```
`d = 1` Yes, `100 % (1 * 1) = 0`
`d = 2` Yes, `100 % (2 * 2) = 0`
`d = 3` No, `100 % (3 * 3) = 1`
`d = 4` No, `100 % (4 * 4) = 4`
`d = 5` Yes, `100 % (5 * 5) = 0`
`d = 6` No, `100 % (6 * 6) = 28`
`d = 7` No, `100 % (7 * 7) = 2`
`d = 8` No, `100 % (8 * 8) = 36`
`d = 9` No, `100 % (9 * 9) = 19`
`d = 10` Yes, `100 % (10 * 10) = 0`
End: `11 * 11 > 100`.
```

So, `D = {1, 2, 5, 10}`. Now let's compute `T`, squared divisors of `81`

```
`d = 1`, Yes
`d = 2`, No (remainder = 1)
`d = 3`, Yes
`d = 4`, No (remainder = 1)
`d = 5`, No (remainder = 6)
`d = 6`, No (remainder = 9)
`d = 7`, No (remainder = 32)
`d = 8`, No (remainder = 17)
`d = 9`, Yes
End: `10 * 10 > 81`.
```

So, `T = {1, 3, 9}`

Now we enumerate all pairs `(s, t)` in `D x T` and compare `81 * s * s` with `100 * t * t`. The pairs are:

```
(1, 1), (2, 1), (5, 1), (10, 1)
(1, 3), (2, 3), (5, 3), (10, 3)
(1, 9), (2, 9), (5, 9), (10, 9)
```

and we see that the last one (10, 9) satisfies `81 * 10 * 10 = 100 * 9 * 9`. Therefore `sqrt(100/81) = 10/9`. Had the example been chosen so that no pair satisfies the equation the squared root would have been irrational.

Comment: I don't see why you are testing multiple candidates. If you have a representation of the rational as m/n, with m and n positive and coprime, then this is only a square of a rational if m and n are squares. It's easy to test if an integer is a square. You don't need to factor m and n. If you are given a rational that is m/n which might not be coprime, you can reduce this to lowest terms by dividing by the GCD which is easy to find with Euclid's algorithm which again doesn't require factoring m and n.

Comment: Example added. Also note that I fixed the use of % because I had written `d * d % m` instead of `m % (d * d)`.

Comment: @DouglasZare Excellent question. You are right. The reason why I took this approach is that it can be easily generalized to equations of higher degrees. In fact the same technique I've used here to solve `x^2 - (m/n) = 0` can be easily adapted to the general case of any polynomial `p(x) = 0` provided all coefficients of `p(x)` are rational numbers.

Comment: This all assumes OP is only interested in testing if a square root is rational or not.  If he gets the number through some other means, this won't work.

Comment: @Teepeemm. Right; but which other means? If you get, say, a floating point number, there is no way to know whether it was meant to represent some other quantity. You have to provide the "construction" of the number in order to decide its "rationalness."

Comment: I've created an answer that may be able to determine rationalness of an arbitrary floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility.  The first step is to find the next smallest and largest float (which are the various assignments leading up to `prevFloat` and `nextFloat`).  After than, we step through all possible rational numbers with the denominator below a certain threshold, looking for something to fit between the floats.  If it can't find a fraction before running out of potential denominators, it reports `NaN`.  The function ends up running in `O(maxDenom)`.

```js
function asRational(number) {
    var maxDenom = 1000,
        sign = number < 0 ? "-" : "+",
        absVal = Math.abs(number),
        integer = Math.floor(absVal),
        fractionalPart = absVal-integer,
        asBinary = fractionalPart.toString(2),
        prevAsBinary = asBinary.replace(/10*$/,function(match) {
            return "0"+Array(match.length).join("1");
        }),
        nextAsBinary = asBinary.replace(/01*$/,function(match) {
            return "1"+Array(match.length).join("0");
        }),
        prevFloat = parseFloat(prevAsBinary,2),
        nextFloat = parseFloat(nextAsBinary,2),
        numerator = 0;
    for ( var denominator = 1 ; denominator <= maxDenom ; denominator++ ) {
        while ( numerator < denominator*prevFloat ) {
            numerator++;
        }
        if ( numerator <= denominator*nextFloat ) {
            return {
                "sign":sign,
                "integer":integer,
                "numerator":numerator,
                "denominator":denominator
            };
        }
    }
    return NaN;
}

function rationalToString(rational) {
    if ( !! rational ) {
        return rational.sign+"("+rational.integer
            +"+"+rational.numerator+"/"+rational.denominator+")";
    } else {
        return "NaN";
    }
}

function parseFloat(asString,radix) {
    var power = asString.length-asString.indexOf(".")-1,
        asFloat = parseInt(asString.replace(".",""),radix);
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < power ; i++ ) {
        asFloat /= radix;
    }
    return asFloat;
}

var paras = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for ( var i = 0 ; i < paras.length ; i++ ) {
    paras[i].textContent
        = paras[i].id+"="+rationalToString(asRational(eval(paras[i].id)));
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p id="5/3"></p>
  <p id="100/999"></p>
  <p id="99/1000"></p>
  <p id="100/1001"></p>
  <p id="1000/10000"></p>
 </body>
</html>
```