# How to detect a repeating decimal

Tags: ios, swift, math

I need to detect an infinite quotient. For example, when user divides 1/3, I'm not going to show him 0.333333333333, I'm going show him that result is a repeating decimal.

Comment: Do you mean, "how do I tell if a number is a [repeating decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal)?"?

Comment: @Kevin well, yes. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: From the wikipedia article, it seems that a number repeats if the prime factors of the denominator contains anything other than 2 or 5.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197478/detecting-that-a-fraction-is-a-repeating-decimal

Comment: [Here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87522/decimal-expansion-of-a-rational-number) is a program which computes the decimal expansion of a fraction and detects repeating decimals. It is written in Java, but perhaps you can use the ideas.

Comment: All rational numbers have a repeating decimal representation.  However if the denominator is exclusively the product of powers of 2 and 5 the repeating value is 0 ... or possibly 9 if you prefer that representation.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I've got the idea and I will post a Swift function once I make it.

Comment: A repeating decimal is not an infinitesimal. Corrected question (along with incorrect value for 1/3). That said, waht do you mean by "show that result is a repeating decimal?" How do you plan to show that?

Comment: I did this in javascript, if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28995556/2336725

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation how to compute the decimal expansion
of a fraction and detect repeating decimals (i.e. periods in the
decimal expansion). It is a translation of the code posted and reviewed
in [Decimal expansion of a rational number](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87522/decimal-expansion-of-a-rational-number) on Code Review to Swift.

The algorithm is just the [Long Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division), and an array
(`remainders`)  is used to check for a periodic decimal expansion.
(For the sake of simplicity, it is assumed that the numerator is
non-negative and the
denominator is positive. This can be generalised if necessary.)

```
struct DecimalFraction : Printable {
    let wholePart : Int         // Integer part
    let fractionDigits : [Int]  // Fractional digits
    let repeatingAt : Int?      // Position of first repeating digit, or `nil`

    // Create DecimalFraction from given fraction
    init(numerator : Int, denominator : Int) {
        precondition(numerator >= 0, "`numerator` must be non-negative")
        precondition(denominator > 0, "`denominator` must be positive")

        wholePart = numerator / denominator
        var fractionDigits : [Int] = []
        var repeatingAt : Int? = nil
        var rem = (abs(numerator) % denominator) * 10
        var remainders : [Int] = []
        while (rem > 0 && repeatingAt == nil) {
            remainders.append(rem)
            let digit = rem / denominator
            rem = (rem % denominator) * 10
            fractionDigits.append(digit)
            repeatingAt = find(remainders, rem)
        }
        self.fractionDigits = fractionDigits
        self.repeatingAt = repeatingAt
    }

    // Produce a string description, e.g. "12.3{45}"
    var description : String {
        var result = String(wholePart) + "."
        for (idx, digit) in enumerate(fractionDigits) {
            if idx == repeatingAt {
                result += "{"
            }
            result += String(digit)
        }
        if repeatingAt != nil {
            result += "}"
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
println(DecimalFraction(numerator: 3, denominator: 8))
// 0.375
println(DecimalFraction(numerator: 1, denominator: 3))
// 0.{3}
println(DecimalFraction(numerator: 20, denominator: 7))
// 2.{857142}
println(DecimalFraction(numerator: 12222, denominator: 990))
// 12.3{45}
```

The periods are simply indicated by curly braces, but it should 
be easy to modify the code to produce an `NSAttributedString`
which indicates the periods by – for example – horizontal lines.